# Click event by jquery in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, click

I have partial on main page:

```
    <div id='calendar_links'>
      <%= link_to day_of_week, root_path(:day => day), :class => 'active_calendar_link' %>
    </div>
```

I want to make that - after click to this link, this link redirect to main page with day parameter and I want to after clicking this day be without :class => 'active_calendar_link'.

I write this jquery code in application.js file, but it didn't work, why? :

```
$(document).onDomReady(function(){
 $('#calendar_links').click(function()
  $(this).removeClass('active_calendar_link')
 }); }); })
```

How to correct to?

Comment: because in your code, `this` is referring to the div, not to the anchor tag

Comment: did you mean [$(document).ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)..?

Comment: Hmmm, there's something wrong in your logic or I'm missing something. If you're redirecting to another page, you need to apply the JS to the new page, not the old one...

Comment: I have index page and partial for this page and this link_to got to this index page, but with new parameter - http://localhost:3000/?day=#day_number
How can I write correct jquery code and correct my partial? plz help me

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're checking the `click` event on the `div`, not on the anchor tag.

Then, `this` refers to the wrong object.

Moreover, it seems that you really redirect to another page since I can't see any `preventDefault()` action. So obviously, it can't work.

Comment: I have index page and partial for this page and this link_to got to this index page, but with new parameter - http://localhost:3000/?day=#day_number
How can I write correct jquery code and correct my partial? plz help me

Comment: jQuery is about interaction in the very same page or Ajax stuff. Here you want to link to another page with a param which is ruby/rails code only.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $(".active_calendar_link").click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("active_calendar_link");
    return true;
  })
})
```